# JQUERY IF-STATEMENTS Get only the href prop of <a> tag, which is a sub element of :checked checkbox <input> in an <li>

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, selector, checked

I have an unordered list, each `< li >` has an input of type `< checkbox >`. It also has an anchor tag with `<a href >` property. `A:href` has been dynamically built based on user input.

I want to traverse the `< li >` list, find the checked inputs and get the `href` of only those checked inputs.

```html
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The logic in pseudo code is:

```
for all li 
if checkbox is checked
get anchor property href
```

The problem is when I use the `$ ( "a" )` and all its alternatives `:checked` , `li.active input:checkbox`, `$( "ul li checkbox:checked a" )`, `$this.children(":checked").each(function(){ ...etc}` the DOM will return all the anchors not just the anchors of the `:checked` inputs.  It will not traverse the list within the list. It will exit the range of checked list items every time.

Some of the solutions I tried are as follows:

**1**

```
$( ":checkbox:checked" ).prop( true , function(){
    $( "a" ).css( "background-color","yellow" );
});
```

**2**

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function (){
   window.open($(".myID")
  .attr("href")) 
   });
```

**3**

```
$('li').each(function(){
    //go to li children
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.children(":checked").each(function(){
          $this; // parent li
          $this.css( "background-color","green" ); //works until here
          var $childs = $this.children(":checked"); 
         $childs.children("a").each(function(){ //undefined
           //PRINT OUT HREF OF A (DID NOT WORK EITHER)
         });
    });
```

**4**

```
$('#li.active input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
    getAllValue()
});

function getAllValue() {
    var sThisVal = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    alert(sThisVal);
}
```

I am realizing (correct me if its wrong) that `$("selector")` cannot be used to combine conditions of two parent> child tags ie.. $("a[href] :checkbox:checked") will return **all anchors** and **all input checked boxes**. Same goes for if statements. I thought `.children()` function  may get me objects but that don't seem to work like I would expect them to the `input` type `checkbox` since it does not have a closing tag (? this is a guess)

I do not want to touch the html schema because it is dynamically built and this is the final stage of the project.

---

I'd like to thank everyone for being so helpful here. I have been trying to find the answer to my question for 3 days now. So please do not hit me with the "this was answered before" because believe me, I tried all proposed answers and it didn't work because this case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure corresponds to this CSS selector:

```
li > :checked + a
^  ^     ^    ^ ^  
|  |     |    |  -- an <a> element
|  |     |    |
|  |     |     ---- which directly follows
|  |     |
|  |      --------- an element currently checked (<input>)
|  |
|   --------------- which is a direct child of
|
 ------------------ an <li> element
```

So just use it then iterate over the matching `<a>` elements

```js
button.onclick = function(evt) {
  $('li > :checked + a').each(function(i, el) {
    console.log(el.getAttribute('href'));
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And if you're only dealing with [newest browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility), then you can do it without library:

```js
button.onclick = (evt) => {
  [... document.querySelectorAll('li > :checked + a')]
    .forEach( (el) =>
      console.log( el.getAttribute('href') )
    );
};
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When iterating, select both the checkbox child and the `<a>` child from the ul's children:

```js
button.onclick = () => {
  $('li').each(function() {
    const [checkbox, a] = this.children;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Or, if you had to use jQuery accessor methods:

```js
button.onclick = () => {
  $('li').each(function() {
    const [checkbox, a] = $(this).children();
    if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
      console.log($(a).attr('href'));
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">click</button>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

There isn't really any use in jQuery for something this simple, feel free to use built-in DOM methods alone:

```js
button.onclick = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach((li) => {
    const [checkbox, a] = li.children;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
      console.log(a.getAttribute('href'));
    }
  });
};
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
<ul>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link1">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><input type="checkbox"><a href="/link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```